# AMP - How to call tap event handler programmatically?

Tags: php, amp-html

How can I call AMP tap event handler programmatically (in PHP), since I want it to fire when page loads and not when I click the button?

Comment: As Sebastian Benz answered it is not possible to trigger actions on page load. However, if you can tell us what exactly you want to perform on page load we might be able to find a workaround. Please share what action you are trying to perform in your event handler.

Comment: Thank you Chris. I need my list to be ordered initially by price, when the page is being loaded. I don't have and I don't want to have button to tap for ordering. I have html table, that is being rendered at runtime, since I do some price calculations. I need to sort THAT list... actually that table's rows.
How can do this?

Comment: Can your price calculation be done at the server side so the HTML is already sorted upon page load?

Comment: I did that yesterday as a workaround. It worked. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible. One of the design goals of AMP is to avoid layout jumps on page load. Being able to trigger actions on page load goes against this.